# How to Synchronize session using SAML?

Tags: java, security, spring-security, single-sign-on, saml

I'm using two servers(portal and LMS server(content)) and SSO for authentication. Once a user is authenticated with the portal he will access LMS Server without authentication as the same session is created on LMS Server (due to the SSO).

I want to synchronize the sessions of these two servers. For example, if a user logs out from the LMS server (s)he should be automatically logged out from the portal. How can I synchronize these two sessions using SAML? Can this be achieved with SAML or should I be implementing this via some custom extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with SAML. You want to use the Single Logout Profile. Check out section 4.4 in the spec... http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf

Comment: The single logout profile is indeed designed for this but many SAML service providers struggle to map the SAML session id to the HTTP session, especially when running in a clustered environment. So it's worth checking that your SP can handle this

Answer (score 0):

To add more in to the Jeffsix answer;

Yes..  this could be done by Single logout profile... I have done some implementation with Single logout profile and Here, you want to properly use the "SessionIndex" attribute that can be found in the SAML response. Service provider session must be map with this "SessionIndex" value. Once logout is initiated, "SessionIndex" value must be sent back. [Here](http://soasecurity.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/) is some good reading on this. Hope this would help you.